# Cypress Component Test failing when using NextJs13 useSelectedLayoutSegments

Tags: next.js, cypress

I have a nextJS 13 application set up, and have successfully integrated Cypress Component Testing ability.
However, for some reason, when I try and test my navigation component which is including the **useSelectedLayoutSegments** hook (https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-selected-layout-segments), I am getting an error:

`(uncaught exception)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tree')`

I am using the latest version of Next (13.2.4) and Cypress (12.9.0) at the time of writing.

I am trying to use the hook like this (slightly abridged for readability) in order to indicate which nav item should be highlighted - or, in the case of a nested item, I want both the item and the parent to be highlighted:

```
'use client';
import { useSelectedLayoutSegments } from 'next/navigation';

export const SidebarItemMenu = () => {
  const segments = useSelectedLayoutSegments();
  const lastSegment = segments[segments.length - 1];
  const firstSegment = segments[0];
  const isMenuActive = doesUrlMatch(url, firstSegment);

  return (
        <>
            <SidebarItem
                onClick={onClick}
                isSelected={doesUrlMatch(url, lastSegment)}
            />
            {hasSubMenu ? (
                <Collapse in={isOpen} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    <List component="div" disablePadding>
                        {subMenu.map(({ title: subTitle, url: subUrl }: ItemType) => (
                            <SidebarItem
                                key={subTitle}
                                lastSegment={lastSegment}
                                isSelected={doesUrlMatch(subUrl, lastSegment)}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </List>
                </Collapse>
            ) : null}
        </>
    );
};
```

If I comment out the use segment and each of the references to it, the component loads in Cypress as expected - but as soon as they are in there I get the error mentioned above:
[image: Cypress Error]

The Cypress test at this stage is just mounting the component, nothing more than that.